# How does SelectFromModel from scikit-learn select features?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

When I use `XGBClassifier` with  `SelectFromModel` the algorithm always returns around five features regardless of the `max_features` value

My question is: does `XGBClassifier` though that there are only five useful features in my dataset?

````
from sklearn.feature_selection  import SelectFromModel
from xgboost                    import XGBClassifier

sf=SelectFromModel(XGBClassifier(), max_features=10).fit(X, y)


#The output only contains five True, all remaining are False
print(sf.get_support())
```
````

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset that returns this issue? Then also, what is the output of `sf.get_support()` or `sf.get_feature_names_out()`?

Comment: `[False False False False False False False False False True False  True False False False  True False False  False False  True False False ]` This is the output of `sf.get_support()` with four `True`. Relating the dataset, all features are numeric when I use `SelectKBest` or `RFE` it return the exact number (10)

Answer (score 1):

> To only select based on max_features, set threshold=-np.inf.

I found the above text in the documentation [sklearn.feature_selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectFromModel.html). This means as priority `SelectFromModel` depends on the `threshold` parameter and returns all features that pass the threshold (regardless of `max_features`).

If you want `max_features` fully function, then set `threshold=-np.inf`, in this case, all features pass the threshold, then `max_features` can select demanded features (based on their rank).